# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PACCHETTIVISITETURISTICHE" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc, h2

I'm implementing a piece of code for a project using eclipse.
One of the features I'm asked to do is to find out if there are two values ​​in a database table (created with h2).
All this must be implemented by using DAO classes and a Manager class that passes between the main and the DAO classes.
My problem is that by doing this, an exception is always raised that tells me that the "packet list" table was not found.
But this can not be because:

- I checked it in the database and there is the table
- The database was properly connected with eclipse
- If I implement all the function in the main the table is recognized!

These are the classes:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DaoPacchetti {


public static boolean Ricerca(String citta, String periodo ) throws SQLException{
    boolean verifica=false;
    PreparedStatement stat=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Connection con=null;


    con= DBManager.getConnection();
    stat=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM pacchettivisiteturistiche "
            +  " WHERE citta=? AND disponibilitaSottoscrizione=?");
    stat.setString(1, citta);
    stat.setString(2, periodo);
    rs=stat.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        verifica=true;
    }

    //rs.close();
    //stat.close();
    con.close();
    return verifica;

    } 
}
```

Manager Class:

```
import dao.DaoPacchetti;
//import dao.DAOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;



public class GestorePacchetti {

private static GestorePacchetti istance;

public static GestorePacchetti getIstance() {
    if (istance == null)
        istance = new GestorePacchetti();
    return istance;
}

public  boolean RicercaPacchetto(String citta,String periodo){
    boolean trovato=false;
    try{
    trovato=DaoPacchetti.Ricerca(citta, periodo);
    return trovato;
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("errore nella ricerca del pacchetto");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return trovato;
}
}
```

Main class:

```
import pacchetti.GestorePacchetti;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Terminale {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    boolean trovato;
    String citta;
    String codice_pacchetto;
    String data;
    String nPartecipantistringa;
    int nPartecipanti;

    GestorePacchetti g=  GestorePacchetti.getIstance();

System.out.println("immetti la città e la data per la ricerca del pacchetto 
delle visite turistiche");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("immetti prima la citta");
        citta = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ora immetti la data");
        data=input.nextLine();

        trovato=g.RicercaPacchetto(citta, data);


        if(trovato==false)
        System.out.println("Reinserire i parametri per favore");
    }while(trovato==false);

    System.out.println("Trovato!!");

}

}
```

I also write the main function that contains the entire function without invoking other classes (here the table is recognized):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    boolean trovato;
    String citta;
    String codice_pacchetto;
    String data;
    String nPartecipantistringa;
    int nPartecipanti;

    GestoreVisiteTuristiche g= new GestoreVisiteTuristiche();

    System.out.println("immetti la città e la data per la ricerca del 
    pacchetto delle visite turistiche");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("immetti prima la citta");
        citta = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ora immetti la data");
        data=input.nextLine();

        Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement stat=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try{


        con=DBManager.getConnection();
        stat=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PacchettiVisiteTuristiche P 
"
                +  "WHERE ?=P.citta AND ?=P.disponibilitaSottoscrizione");
        stat.setString(1, citta);
        stat.setString(2, data);
        rs=stat.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("trovato!!");
            citta=rs.getString("citta");
            data=rs.getString("disponibilitaSottoscrizione");
            System.out.println(citta+" "+data);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("errore, nessuna corrispondenza");
        }

        rs.close();
        stat.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("errore");}
        finally {
            if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e){}
        }
        }





}
}
```

`DBManager` Class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;


public class DBManager {
protected static Connection conn;

final protected static ConnectionFactory CONNECTION_FACTORY=new 
H2ConnectionFactory();

public static Connection getConnection(){
    if (conn == null) {
        try {
            conn = CONNECTION_FACTORY.createConnection();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return conn;

}
}
```

`ConnectionFactory` :

```
public interface ConnectionFactory {
java.sql.Connection createConnection() throws Exception;
}

import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class H2ConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory { 

protected final static String DB_PATH= "./test";
protected final static String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:h2:" + DB_PATH ;


@Override
public java.sql.Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, "sa", "12345");
}
}
```

This is the exception raised:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PACCHETTIVISITETURISTICHE" not found; 
SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM pacchettivisiteturistiche  WHERE citta=? AND 
disponibilitaSottoscrizione=? [42102-195]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5506)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1260)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1940)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2089)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1934)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1749)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1737)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:448)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:320)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:292)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:257)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:573)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:514)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
at dao.DaoPacchetti.Ricerca(DaoPacchetti.java:22)
at pacchetti.GestorePacchetti.RicercaPacchetto(GestorePacchetti.java:21)
at ui.Terminale.main(Terminale.java:30)
```

Comment: make sure you dont have to use `schemaName.TableName` and you have mentioned right database

Comment: I tried do this too, but the situation doesn't change

Comment: Post your DBManager Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jdbc:h2:~/test","sa","password"` **OR** `jdbc:h2:file:~/test;USER=sa;PASSWORD=password`

try any of these connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but i am not sure that the error is here because in the main class where the function works i use the same DBManager class.
This is my DBManager Class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;


public class DBManager {
protected static Connection conn;

final protected static ConnectionFactory CONNECTION_FACTORY=new 
H2ConnectionFactory();

public static Connection getConnection(){
    if (conn == null) {
        try {
            conn = CONNECTION_FACTORY.createConnection();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return conn;

}
}
```

This is the interface and class of the ConnectorFactory:

```
public interface ConnectionFactory {
java.sql.Connection createConnection() throws Exception;
}

import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class H2ConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory { 

protected final static String DB_PATH= "./test";
protected final static String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:h2:" + DB_PATH ;


@Override
public java.sql.Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, "sa", "12345");
}
}
```

Comment: `jdbc:h2:~/test","sa","password"` **OR** `jdbc:h2:file:~/test;USER=sa;PASSWORD=password`

try any of these connection strings.

Comment: I used "jdbc:h2:~/test" instead of CONNECTION_STRING and it worked.
How it is possible ???

Comment: problem is with that `.` only :)

Comment: And why if i use the main class where there is the entire implementation with the same DBManager, it works?
Anyway thanks a lot, you saved me.